# I can't put a star rating on a song in iTunes

Tags: itunes

I noticed that I have a song on iTunes that I cannot give a star rating to.  The stars are grayed out.   So I went to my iPad & iPhone to see if I could rate it there.  The music apps didn't have that song.

I believe that song is from my iCloud music library.

So how do I un-gray the stars in that song?

Why don't I see that song on my iDevices?

Comment: What version of iOS and macOS are you running in your three devices? It might be because they are different versions. I remember something like that happening to me.